# Not abled to install Ubuntu 20.04lts in my Acer aspire PC!

Tags: system-installation

On update and other software section: I was selected Normal installation only than After clicking on continue I got nothing cursor is continue blinking not progress to next step.what should I do ?
Please help....

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of information here. Can you update your question to include the model of your Acer, as well as the amount of RAM you have installed? This will make it easier for someone to offer specific suggestions 

Comment: First think is that when was I normally switch on my laptop it's said "No Bootable Device'and if I put Bootable USB for Ubuntu 20.04 not abled to reach installation , second, information about my PC : ACER ASPIRE E5, CPU  AMD A10-9600P RADEON R5, 10 COMPUTE CORE 4C+6G, System BIOS Version is : v1.09, GOP VERSION is: AMD GOP X64, HDD MODEL NAME IS : TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100, TOTAL MEMORY IS : 4096MB. ROM : 1TB. ... Thank you, matigo

Comment: At the end something depicted like this:The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed @matigo

Comment: Please help my background is biology don't know much about computer software and I have lots of work to do ....I am crying nothing is open out there to resolve the problem due to covid19. Last two days I tried hard to resolve this but I can't .....

Answer (score 0):

i think was your problem try it.

1.Install Ubuntu (it worked with 18.04 and 20.04) from a USB drive.

2.Enter UEFI (BIOS) with F2 once Acer appears

3.Make sure a security management password is set, so to enable several of the functions, and that Secure Boot is enabled (initially, for same reason) in the Boot tab.

4.In Security tab, execute "Restore Secure Boot to Factory Default", then reboot once more into UEFI/BIOS with F2

5.Back to Security tab, enter "Select an UEFI as Trusted for Executing", HDD0 (or change if other drive), ../ Ubuntu / grub64x.efi, Yes.

6.In Boot tab, disable Secure Boot

7. F10 to save and exit.

Hopefully, this should work.

original post is here check it out

[Ubuntu is not booting on acer aspire laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997612/ubuntu-is-not-booting-on-acer-aspire-laptop)

Comment: Thanks, @Kandhaswamy!